# R Combining list from vectors

Tags: r, list, concatenation

I am trying to combine two lists in R as follows

```
c("a"="1","b"="2","c"="3")
```

what gives me:

```
  a   b   c 
 "1" "2" "3"
```

I would like to obtain the same results using the following lists,

```
letters <- c("t", "s", "k")
numbers <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

Is there some simple way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
setNames(numbers, letters)
```

---

Or do the `names` assignment

```
names(numbers) <- letters
```

NOTE: The expected output showed is a named `vector` and not a `list`